# Accessing vendor specific CSS attribute in a style attribute? Selenium seems to ignore it by default

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to check the css attributes of a tag that is updated via javasrcipt. They put the css directly in the tag like this:

```
<div class="myclass" style="color: red; display: block; -webkit-transform -translate3d(x,x,x);
```

I can access the `style` attribute via the `WebElement`s `getAttribute` method, however, it *only* returns the 'normal' CSS. i.e. In the example above, only the `color:red;display:block` would be returned. The `-webkit` (or anything similarly browser specific) does not get returned by Selenium's `getAttribute` method.

Is there a way to access these values via Selenium?

Answer (score 2):

Selenium elements have a getCssStyle
method. Could getCssStyle("-webkit-transform") extract the value?

**EDIT**(
Deepest apologies for the typo. It is infact getCssValue

Comment: The name of the method is [getCssValue](http://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)), not ```getCssStyle``` and it won’t extract the value.

Comment: Why down vote a typo? I was on the train. It is a perfectly valid approach but didn't work.

Comment: The solution does not work which could be tested faster than posting a non-working answer. That’s the reason for the downvote.

Comment: @lefloh, that is a little unfair. It's sound advice. It is the correct way to get CSS attribute values like that using Selenium.

Comment: @Arran, sure this is the correct way to get CSS attribute values but it does not work if they are vendor-prefixed (regardless of a correct style-attribute or a missing colon). And this was the OPs question.

Comment: @lefloh it worked for me. So could you please show how it doesn't work with fully formed CSS? If you could show a test case where it doesn't work I am happy to delete my answer.

Comment: @Arran, I’m sorry. I’m testing with firefox and it works for -moz-transform. I was only testing -moz-border-radius which does not work. Don’t know why there is a difference, both are supported without prefix in Firefox. I reverted the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The reason Selenium is not returning the transform rule is because it is badly formed CSS.

By this I mean your `transform` CSS attribute is missing a colon.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Syntax

> Both properties and values are case-sensitive in CSS. The pair is separated by a **colon**, ':' (U+003A COLON)

So this is bad web development. What do you expect Selenium to do in that instance? It can do nothing by throw it's arms into the air and get the best out of a bad situation - by this I mean it's returning *what it can* (the other properties).

You can further verify this by checking out the source code of Selenium. Remember Selenium is open source so the code is your ultimate documentation to find out why or what it's doing.

Specifically:

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/javascript/atoms/dom.js#L225

Essentially, the first part can be cut down to this:

```
var styleArray = "color: red; display: block; -webkit-transform -translate3d(x,x,x);".split(new RegExp('[;]+(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)(?=(?:(?:[^\']*\'){2})*[^\']*$)(?=(?:[^()]*\\([^()]*\\))*[^()]*$)'))
```

Run it in the JS Console of Chrome and see the result. It correctly shows:

```
["color: red", " display: block", " -webkit-transform -translate3d(x,x,x)", ""]
```

It's the next step that strips it out:

```
var i = pair.indexOf(':');
```

Your transform rule doesn't have it, so it won't be returned. Rightly so.

You can then go even **further** to prove this by putting it through a CSS validation service, like CSS Lint:

http://csslint.net/

Now, those `style` attributes on their own are not CSS stylesheets, so stuff something together to make it into a stylesheet:

```
a {
color: red;
display: block; 
-webkit-transform -translate3d(x,x,x);
}
```

What do we get?

```
Expected COLON at line 4, col 19.
-webkit-transform -translate3d(x,x,x);
```

I would not start hacking with JS to get this to work, but rather fix your application.

I suspect, this will not cause the CSS to be broken, as I would suspect the browser does a good job of understanding what the intention is.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know why Selenium is swallowing vendor-specific styles but you could parse the style on your own:

```
String rawDiv = div.getAttribute("outerHTML");
String style = rawDiv.replaceFirst("(.*?)style=\"", "").replaceFirst("\".*", "");
```